# p:tabView save data

Tags: primefaces, tabview

Hello everybody i have tabview:

```
<p:tabView value="#{beanPlanning.plannings}" 
                   var="planning" id="tabview"
                   widgetVar="myTabView"
                   activeIndex="#{beanPlanning.index}"
                   cache="false"
                   >
                <p:ajax event="tabChange" process="@this" listener="#{beanPlanning.elementSelected(planning.id)}" update="tabview"/>

 <p:tab title="#{planning.libelle}"  >
                 <p:panelGrid>
                <ui:repeat value="#{beanPlannin.tasksFactorys}" var="tf">
                     <p:row>
                     <p:column>
                         <h:outputText value="#{tf.libelle}"/>
                     </p:column>
                     <p:column>
                         <p:selectBooleanCheckbox  value="#{tf.affiche}" />
                         <h:outputText value="#{messages.PFafficheCheckox}" />
                     </p:column>
                     <p:column>
                         <p:colorPicker value="#{tf.coleur}" />
                     </p:column>
...
```

but when I want to save data it's possible save just the data of last tab!!!

Comment: Sure, just make a button that fires a server side method that only saves the data from the lasts tab....

Comment: sorry my question is how i can save data of every tab

Comment: now i save just data of last tab others tabs no

Comment: create an object and every elements of the tab is a property of this object

Comment: There is btw only 1 tab in your code (that should be in [mcve] flavour btw)